# Objective-C Tableview Stop disabled row form moving

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am creating an app in which I have to Reorder the Rows but I have some disabled rows which should not Move. e.g. As shown in image the 2nd and 3rd row are disabled form moving. if I try to move non disabled row they should not move to the index path of the disabled row[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3rM.png)

Comment: Did you try anything? What output do you get, what would you expect? Also try to make shorter sentences, these long sentences are hard to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would use this method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath 
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == DoNotMoveToThisRow) {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

If you don't want a cell to move to a certain row, then just return the sourceIndexPath.